# Technical term to name the properties of a class that can take two values (true and false)?

Tags: c++, class, cpu-word, boolean

Does a technical english word exist to commonly name the group of boolean members of a class that characterize it ?

EDIT : I'm not searching for the word "boolean". In the following example does a word exist to name the group of variable that begins by "is" ?

```
class MyClass
{
    protected:
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;

        bool isBig;
        bool isBeautiful;
        bool isRich;
        bool isBlackAndWhite;
};
```

EDIT : Flags is definitely the word I searched for.

Comment: Maybe "flags" for describing a collection of booleans which control the behavior of a class or function.

Comment: In response to your edit the word you are looking for is "adjectives"

Comment: I like @Eric 's choice of word for a group of booleans: flags. I think that is the most suitable. And I think the title and body of your question mean different things (you are asking two different questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Traits' is one word to describe it, in general terms, but this already has a very specific meaning within C++ and what you're describing is not it.

My suggestion? Go to an online thesaurus, type 'traits' and take your pick of what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

"Boolean" is the correct technical term for this structure and is born out of [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

"Boolean" *is* the technical term for a variable which can be either true or false.

Comment: And how do you technically call a group/set of boolean variables?

Comment: A set of boolean variables. Why should there be a specific term for `set<bool>`? It's pretty concise and explicative as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`class Is { bool value; public: const bool get(void) { return value; } const };`

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually name "substructures" with a fixed dictionary of technical terms; I'm trying to use a name that tells what kind of data the structure contains.

Technically, booleans could also be called "flags", but I'm not positive that simply collecting all bools into a "flags" structure is really the way to go. structures should really only be used to form groups of items that actually belong together; if, for example, you find that you are naming some of your variables "Timer_xxx", then those variables might be a good candidate to go into a structure, which you would probably call "Timer".

In a similar fashion, you probably wouldn't do something like

```
struct { double x, y, z; } BigFloatyNumbers;
```

Instead, you would probably write it as

```
struct { double x, y, z; } Position;
```

Thus, in your case, maybe "Properties" is a reasonable name. It's even generic :-)